# Time value comparison using between operator in SQL

Tags: sql

I Know as far that SQL save value of time in 24 hour format. My Question is that time comparison does not work when I use between operator as following query.

```
 Select T11 from ScheduleTable Where CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(Time, '23:22:00', 0), 100) 
between CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('19:00:00' AS TIME), 100) and 
CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME), 100)
```

The above query does not work show empty result. I have used static time in above query as for example but in real scenario I have used current time.

Comment: It doesn't work because 00:00 < 23:00. If you are comparing two different days (at midnight the day changes! who knew!) then use date comparison, not time comparison.

Comment: Yes you ae right dear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here, but `'23:22:00'` should be a valid time literal in SQL Server.  Therefore, the following query should return all records:

```sql
SELECT T11
FROM ScheduleTable
WHERE '23:22:00' BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '23:59:59';
```

Comment: Thanks,          SELECT T11
                       FROM ScheduleTable
                       WHERE '23:00:00' BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '00:00:00' but this does not work

Comment: @KhuramJan If you want to also include midnight itself, you would have to add another check for that.

Comment: Thanks , yes i understand the date changes at midnight thats why it does not work. I have to use '23:59:59' instead of '00:00:00'